# What on earth could be causing MIPI frame drops?

Tags: oscilloscope, debugging, signal-integrity, high-speed, mipi

In a project I'm working on, we're seeing regular frame drops on a 1-lane, 900Mbps MIPI [CSI-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_Serial_Interface) interface. After some investigating, I'm fairly sure that the problem is related to signal integrity. However, looking at the clock and data lines with a 'scope, I can't see anything that looks like a problem.

The 'scope I'm using is a Keysight [MSO-X 3104T](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/product/MSOX3104T/mixed-signal-oscilloscope-1-ghz-4-analog-16-digital-channels.html), and is only just about fast enough at 1GHz bandwidth to see the waveform. But perhaps it can give some insight:

Here is the clock line at two levels of zoom:

[image]
[image]

I'm not sure if that ringing is real, or an artifact of the scope or the probe.

[image]

The measurement is being taken just under the connector where the MIPI signal enters the board. The PCB tracks continue for about 15mm before reaching their destination just under those gold vias.

Lastly, here is what the MIPI lines look with no traffic on them. This is zoomed in vertically to show the baseline noise level, and the 25mv differential offset:

[image]

Questions:

1. Is this 'scope of any use in diagnosing a signal-integrity problem on such a fast signal, or is it just going to be misleading me?
2. If this 'scope is good enough, then is there anything about my measurement technique which could be improved?
3. If the 'scope and probing are good enough, do the signals give any insight into what could be the problem?
4. Could about 20mv of noise, or 25mv differential offset cause frame drops?

Notes:

1. Since the system is quite complex, I didn't want to go into a lot of details about it, since it would make this question very very long. I thought that it would be better to try to focus on the MIPI signal itself.
2. I also didn't go into details about the experiments we've tried so far to make is think that this is SI related, as, again, it would make the question very long.
3. If you think this question needs more details about the whole system, or the experiments we've done so far, please let me know.